# weblogic stuck issue

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We have encountered an issue as below
we don't know if the problem are:
1.socket reading from database is too long that reach the StuckThreadMaxTime 600s
2.database query is running too long
2.locking on database or other objects

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

> Thread-36 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"  {
>       jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(SocketNativeIO.java:???)
>       jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:31)
>       java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)
>       java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:107)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.receive(Unknown Source)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(Unknown
>   Source)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StatementExecutionRequest.executeStatement(Unknown
>   Source)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.CancelableRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeRequest(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> ^-- Holding lock: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter@41dbbdd[thin lock]
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(Unknown
>   Source)
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getMaxFieldSize(Unknown
>   Source)
>       weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.cleanUpStatementForReUse(ConnectionEnv.java:1356)
>       weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.returnCachedStatement(ConnectionEnv.java:1118)
>       ^-- Holding lock: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv$1@41f2d97[thin lock]
>       weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.internalClose(Statement.java:342)
>       weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.doClose(Statement.java:399)
>       weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.close(Statement.java:391)
>       com.riskintegrator.infrastructure.database.DBConnector.getConnection(DBConnector.java:66)
>       ^-- Holding lock: com.riskintegrator.infrastructure.database.DBConnector@1fda7d8[thin
>   lock]
>       com.riskintegrator.infrastructure.database.DBConnector.(DBConnector.java:56)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.BaseSessionBean.populateFormWithPreparedStatement(BaseSessionBean.java:76)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.BaseSession_6uq9n4_EOImpl.populateFormWithPreparedStatement(BaseSession_6uq9n4_EOImpl.java:763)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.BaseSessionDelegate.populateFormWithPreparedStatement(BaseSessionDelegate.java:118)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.setup.SeverityBandBD.selectByValue(SeverityBandBD.java:181)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.ComputeAssessmentScoreBean.ComputeRiskScore(ComputeAssessmentScoreBean.java:332)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.ComputeAssessmentScoreBean.ComputeAssessmentScore(ComputeAssessmentScoreBean.java:119)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.ComputeAssessmentScoreBean_s478gq_EOImpl.ComputeAssessmentScore(ComputeAssessmentScoreBean_s478gq_EOImpl.java:37)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.ComputeAssessmentScoreBD.ComputeAssessmentScore(ComputeAssessmentScoreBD.java:32)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.AssessmentScoreBean.ProcessAssessment(AssessmentScoreBean.java:44)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.AssessmentScoreSession_nlmr0a_EOImpl.ProcessAssessment(AssessmentScoreSession_nlmr0a_EOImpl.java:37)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ca.AssessmentScoreBD.ProcessAssessment(AssessmentScoreBD.java:36)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ScheduledBatchBean.executeJob(ScheduledBatchBean.java:568)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ScheduledBatchBean.executeDailyRunOnce(ScheduledBatchBean.java:792)
>       com.riskintegrator.slsb.ScheduledBatchBean.ejbTimeout(ScheduledBatchBean.java:957)
>       weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl.timerExpired(TimerImpl.java:219)
>
> ^-- Holding lock: weblogic.ejb.container.timer.TimerImpl@12c8e34[thin lock]
>       weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:253)
>       weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
>       weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:198)
>       weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:165)

Answer (score 6):

The thread dump shows that the thread has been stuck for longer than 600 seconds (10 mins) while *receiving back data from the SQL Server*.

In my prev experience this can be either *a long running DB query* or an *intermittent connectivity failure* between Weblogic and the database leaving the socket in a state of limbo.

Is this a one-off or is the same stacktrace is available on other stuck threads as well - at the same line ? If it is, then there are chances you need to review the DB query with SQL Query Analyzer or it's equivalent in MS-SQL

If it's a one-off it could be the network issue