# How can handle server Error "StuckThreadMaxTime" in java

Tags: java, weblogic

At server side we received below error, but not able to catch at our application, so how can handle this error by java code?

Erro::

<[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "624" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 624072 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
        java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Comment: Resolved the same issue by update configuration in web-logic server, mean increase StuckThreadMaxTime 600 to 1200. How to handle this time of error in java application.

Comment: Increasing the max time is masking the issue, which might cause performance issues.  You'll need the full stack trace to determine the offending class (somewhere further down the stack) which eventually resulted in waiting for that socket read.  The connection related to that socket probably needs to be configured with a shorter read timeout.

Comment: You need to take thread dumps and analyse them http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/01/app-server-high-cpu-or-low-threads.html has more also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409496/weblogic-stuck-issue